# Code Efficiency: withoutX2

Tags: java

Given a string, if one or both of the first 2 chars is 'x', return the string without those 'x' chars, and otherwise return the string unchanged. How can I make my code more efficient?

withoutX2("xHi") → "Hi"

withoutX2("Hxi") → "Hi"

withoutX2("Hi") → "Hi"

```
public String withoutX2(String str) {

  if (str.length() < 2)
     return "";
  else if (str.charAt(0) == 'x' && str.charAt(1) == 'x')
     return str.substring(2);
  else if (str.charAt(0) == 'x')
     return str.substring(1);
  else if (str.charAt(1) == 'x')
     return str.substring(0,1) + str.substring(2);
  else
     return str;
}
```

Comment: String which you are passing is only for 3 chars or it can be more than 3?

Comment: Part of this answer depends on if you have the O(n) or O(1) implementation of `substring()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can write using regex.

```
public String withoutX2(String str) {
    return str.replaceFirst("^xx?|^(.)x", "$1");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (since it is mutable) is well suited for this. If the second `char` is an `x` delete it. Then if the first `char` is an `x` delete it. Then return the `toString` of the `StringBuilder`. Something like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
if (sb.charAt(1) == 'x') {
    sb.deleteCharAt(1);
}
if (sb.charAt(0) == 'x') {
    sb.deleteCharAt(0);
}
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public String withoutX2(String str) {

    if (str.length() < 2)
        return "";
    else
        return (str = str.substring(0, 2).replace("x", "")+str.substring(2));
}
```